# C++ - Need to read the timestamps stored in file(.txt) and retrieve the same properly

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a scenario to store five different date and time stamps in a file (.txt) and retrieve the same and map it to different variables for processing.

For example I have the following data's which need to be written in a file.

```
2018-07-16 12:32:12
2018-07-16 12:31:17
2018-07-16 12:30:45
```

In my application I need to retrieve it from the file and map it to three different variables for processing like below,

```
std:: string var1 = 2018-07-16 12:32:12;
std::string var2 = 2018-07-16 12:31:17;
std::string var3 = 2018-07-16 12:30:45;
```

I could able to read and write the variable for single line using the below code,

```
    void readFromFile(std::string& var)
    {
      std::fstream file(fileName_str, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | 
                                                       std::fstream::app );
      if( ! file ) {
        cout << "Unable to open file:" << fileName_str << ";
        return;
     }
     std::string line;
     if (std::getline(file, line)) {           
       var = line;
     }
     file.close();
  }

void writeToFile(std::string& timeString)
{
 if( fileName_str.empty() ) {
   cout << "File name is empty so returning from it.";
   return; 
 }
 std::ofstream file(fileName_str);
 if( ! file ) {
    cout << "Unable to open file:" << fileName_str << ", continuing WITHOUT using it.";
    return;
 }
 file << timeString;
 file.close();
}
}
```

But need help to do the same for three different variables.Any suggestions to achieve it.

Comment: Why not just call `std::getline` three times when reading from the file?

Answer (score 2):

A good way to do this is to use std::getline, but more than once. Say you have three lines in your file. You could read those lines like this:

```
#include <vector>

void readFromFile(std::vector<std::string>& vector_of_lines)
{
  std::fstream file(fileName_str, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | 
                                                   std::fstream::app );
     if (!file) {
         cout << "Unable to open file:" << fileName_str << std::endl;
         return;
     }
     std::string line;
     while (std::getline(file, line)) {           
         vector_of_lines.push_back(line);
     }
     file.close();
 }
```

And this should give you a vector filled with the lines in your file.

Then, if you want to store these retrieved values in variables, you would call the code like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> myvec;
readFromFile(myvec);

std::string str1 = myvec[0];
std::string str2 = myvec[1];
std::string str3 = myvec[2];
```

You could also choose to not even transfer `myvec` into other variables at all, and instead use `myvec` to store them for the time being. However, if you must store them elsewhere, then that is how you would do it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. So we can read all the lines and have it in a vector object. But how to retrieve it from vector and assign to three different variables.Any helpful code snippet for it to do the same.

Comment: I have also tried by using at() method. It also worked fine . Thanks for your timely help.